# memory limit exceeded when I run Flutter build apk on Google Cloud run

Tags: docker, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to build APK on Google cloud run using flutter but I got Memory limit of 2048 exceeded 
and Google Cloud Run does not have a larger memory option

is there any way to limit memory usage without killing the process on Cloud Run?

or a way to reduce/limit the memory used by flutter build apk command (it's inside docker file)

I tested it on my machine and it uses something like 2.2 GB ram so it's all about 0.2 more ram usage

Comment: Until Cloud Run allows more memory, you can use Cloud Run for Anthos as the infrastructure, which provisions VMs and runs Kubernetes on them (which don't have serverless pricing), but it can unblock you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation [Memory for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas):

`Maximum memory size is 2 GB per container instance and **the limit can not be increased**'

> Memory    Maximum memory size, in GB  2   No  per container instance

Comment: Yes I mentioned that in my question there is no way to get more memory
that's why I'm looking for a way to just limit the memory assigned without killing the process or limit the command memory usage so it does not reach the limit